# Can I create a Spark LongAccumulator at the moment I just need it (inside a filter operation, for example)? Currently I need to create them in advance

Tags: java, apache-spark

Loading an open data CSV of associations, I'm filtering them to exclude some having problems.

At this time, when sending a warning log, I'm also willing to count each kind of problem encountered, by the mean of a broadcast variable: a `LongAccumulator`.

It's possible, and not too difficult:

The code doing the checkings in a `filter` (`associations` is a `Dataset<Row>`):

```java
String[] codesAnomalies = {"anomalie.association.sans.objet", "anomalie.association.sans.waldec"};

for(String codeAnomalie : codesAnomalies) {
    accumulators.put(codeAnomalie, super.session.sparkContext().longAccumulator(codeAnomalie));
}

associations = this.rowLoader.loadOpenData(anneeRNA, anneeCOG);

// Ejecter les associations qui n'ont ni nom, ni objet social.
int indexTitre = associations.schema().fieldIndex("titre");
int indexObjet = associations.schema().fieldIndex("objet");

associations = associations.filter((FilterFunction<Row>)f -> {
   if (f.isNullAt(indexTitre) && f.isNullAt(indexObjet)) {
      anomalie("anomalie.association.sans.objet",
          f.getAs("numero_waldec"), f.getAs("adresse_siege_nom_commune"), 
          f.getAs("adresse_siege_code_commune"));
      return false;
   }
         
   if (f.getAs("numero_waldec").toString().length() != 10) {
       anomalie("anomalie.association.sans.waldec",
          f.getAs("adresse_siege_nom_commune"), f.getAs("adresse_siege_code_commune"));
          return false;
   }
         
   // Il peut être demandé que seules les associations actives soient retenues.
   if (actives) {
       return "A".equals(f.getAs("position_activite")) != false;
   }
         
  return true;
});
```

And the `anomalie` method do that:

```java
private void anomalie(String codeMessage, Serializable... arg) {
   if (messageSource == null) {
      this.messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
         this.messageSource.setBasename("fr.ecoemploi.adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationWaldecDataset");
   }

   String message = messageSource.getMessage(codeMessage, arg, Locale.getDefault());
   LOGGER.warn(message);

   LongAccumulator accumulator = accumulators.get(codeMessage);

   if (accumulator != null) {
      accumulator.add(1);
   }
}
```

So that, at the end, I can log a report:

```java
LOGGER.info("Anomalies rencontrées :");

for(Map.Entry<String, LongAccumulator> rapport : this.accumulators.entrySet()) {
   LOGGER.info("\t{} : {}", rapport.getKey(), rapport.getValue().count());
}
```

```
Anomalies rencontrées :
       anomalie.association.sans.waldec : 0
       anomalie.association.sans.objet : 126
```

Currently I have to declare in advance the `longAccumulator`(s) I'll be using, before starting the `filter` operation on my dataset.

If I attempt do write, in the `anomalie` method:

```java
LongAccumulator accumulator = accumulators.computeIfAbsent(codeMessage, 
   clef -> super.session.sparkContext().longAccumulator(clef));

accumulator.add(1);
```

instead of:

```java
LongAccumulator accumulator = accumulators.get(codeMessage);

if (accumulator != null) {
   accumulator.add(1);
}
```

*Spark* fails with an internal error. Looking it's not the time for it to perform something in the *Spark* `session` at the time it is caught in an operation.

Do I have a way to create a new *Accumulator* at the moment I'm just needing it?